Query to pull data from three tables into a final temp table?
I'm wondering:

how to use only SQL (T-SQL for SQL Server)
to query 3 tables
and insert the result data (shown below) into a new temp table.

Temp Table Result
The resulting temp table will contain data (columns) from all three tables and look like the following:
(Note Path is shortened to fit screen)
FileId    Path           PartnerKey   Field1   Field2  Field3
   1     106\10149\PROD     24          DDD      GGG    Alt2


FileId & Path are from Table1
PartnerKey is from Table2
Field1, Field2, & Field3 are from Table3

Note: I show all 3 Source tables with sample data below.
The Challenge
I need data that is parsed out of a column in the first table, so I can query the 2nd and 3rd table.
Here's what I mean.
Every value in the first table column will have the following format:

\\companyName\Production\Storage\Data\Connection\106\10149\PROD\
\\companyName\Production\Storage\Data\Connection\106\NotAnId\PROD\


The first value 106 in both examples above will always be numeric representing a BusinessId.
However, the 2nd value 10149 and NotAnId will sometimes be a BusinessId and sometimes just be part of the path (non-numeric).

I need to parse out those two values and use them to look up a row in the 2nd Table.

When the 2nd parsed out value is a valid integer then use it to query the 2nd Table.
However, if the 2nd parsed value is not a valid integer then use the first parsed out value (guaranteed to always be a valid integer) to query the 2nd Table.

Query 2nd Table For Region & Type

When we have the BusinessId from parsing
we will query the 2nd Table where Region is North
and Type is World to get the PartnerKey.

Use PartnerKey to Query 3rd Table
The PartnerKey will then be used to query the 3rd Table to get Field1, Field2 & Field3.
All of the resultant data will be inserted into the temp table shown above.
Table 1  PathInfo
FileId     Path
    1    \\companyName\Production\Storage\Data\Connection\106\10149\PROD\
    2    \\companyName\Production\Storage\Data\Connection\1723\3763\PROD\
    3    \\companyName\Production\Storage\Data\Connection\1534\1216\PROD\
    4    \\companyName\Production\Storage\Data\Connection\1534\NotAnId\PROD\
    5    \\companyName\Production\Storage\Data\Connection\1534\OtherPath\PROD\

Table 2  Region
ID  BusinessId  Region  Type    PartnerKey
24  106         NORTH   NATIONAL    23
24  24          EAST    WORLD       23
25  10149       NORTH   NATIONAL    24
26  26          NORTH   NATIONAL    25
27  27          SOUTH   NATIONAL    26
29  29          NORTH   WORLD       28
30  30          EAST    WORLD       29

Table 3 - PartnerInfo
PartnerKey   Field1    Field2  Field3
23            AAA       BBB     Alt1
24            DDD       GGG     Alt2
25            XXX       ZZZ     Alt2

What Have I Tried?
I have created and run the following query which maps each FileId and Path to a FirstBusinessId and  SecondBusinessId (when it is a valid integer).
DECLARE @RootLength VARCHAR(100) = '\\companyName\Production\Storage\Data\Connection\'
  
  select FileId, Path,
    TRIM('\' from 
      substring(Path,LEN(@RootLength)+1,
          charIndex('\' , substring(Path,LEN(@RootLength)+1,LEN(@RootLength)))
          )) 
        as FirstBusinessId,

    substring(
    TRIM('\' from
    substring(Path,LEN(@RootLength)+LEN(substring(Path,LEN(@RootLength)+1,
          charIndex('\' , substring(Path,LEN(@RootLength)+1,LEN(@RootLength))
          )) ),LEN(@RootLength))), 0, charIndex('\',
          TRIM ('\' from substring(Path,LEN(@RootLength)+LEN(substring(Path,LEN(@RootLength)+1,
          charIndex('\' , substring(Path,LEN(@RootLength)+1,LEN(@RootLength))
          )) ),LEN(@RootLength)))
          ))
        as SecondBusinessId
 into #BusinessIDTemp -- temp table target
  from PathInfo


Maybe we could use this fiddle to collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/WOLZpy26

is this close?  https://dbfiddle.uk/_YAQf3Ap

That looks like what I'm looking for. I will take a closer look now and see.
If it's all correct I will upvote and mark as answer.  Thanks for your help.

SELECT b.FileId, b.path, region.PartnerKey, p.Field1, p.Field2, p.Field3
  FROM #BusinessIDTemp b
INNER JOIN Region ON 
       ( TRY_CONVERT(int, SecondBusinessID) IS NOT NULL AND  SecondBusinessID=Region.BusinessID)
        OR
       ( TRY_CONVERT(int, SecondBusinessID) IS NULL AND  FirstBusinessID=Region.BusinessID)

INNER JOIN PartnerInfo p ON
       REGION.PartnerKey = P.PartnerKey

fiddle



FileId
path
PartnerKey
Field1
Field2
Field3




1
\companyName\Production\Storage\Data\Connection\106\10149\PROD|    24
DDD
GGG
Alt2





@Jonas Metzler Thanks. I changed IsNumeric for Try_Convert.

This is it!! I had to convert my query to my original data tables (I created all fake table names and data so I didn't reveal any private data) but when I converted that last query that you show then the query worked perfectly!!! I cannot believe how great this collaboration worked!! That's so freaking amazing that you read my long Question and provided the exact right answer.  I just cannot believe how amazing that was.  Wow!
I posted in a remote hope and you came through.  Truly amazing!  Thanks for all your help.

@raddevus Thank you for your joyous feedback. I'm am surprised to get such a response from someone who has asked 100+ questions and has 8605 rep. I have only recently started answering questions. I hope someday to be as successful as you.
